# How to retrieve image from MySql database ?

Tags: php, mysql, ios, image, blob

I currently retrieve information from my database with JSON by doing this in my php file, let's call it getJson.php:

```
<?php
    include ("config.php");

    $query = "SELECT id,title,text,image,date FROM posts";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);

    $rows = array();
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $rows[] = $r;
    }


    echo json_encode($rows);


?>
```

Then in my application I retrieve the JSON representation by using:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kGETUrlPosts];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error;
postsArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

I also have binary image data stored as a BLOB which I would like to retrieve. However I cannot JSON encode this binary data in JSON, can I ?

My second option would have been keeping a URL to my image in the image field and then just call

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.myURL.com/MyPhotos/somephoto.png"]]];
```

Comment: Use base 64 to encode the image data. It goes without saying, that storing image data in a database is not a great idea.

Comment: Storing URLs in you database is the way to go.

Comment: The best solution is to copy the images to a folder and save into the DB the path and the image name.  If you upload images to the DB and you have A LOT OF USERS the reading will take more time.

Comment: Yeah that would have been the second option I stated above... What is conventional ? I would like to prepare for a huge user base, so you say I just save them in a folder and the users have the path to that file ?

Comment: Or use a storage system like Amazon S3.

Comment: Are images a main part of your site? Or are the just like profile images.

Comment: I have set up Amazon S3, however, I am not familiar with it at all. Yes images play a key role in my application and exceed the profile picture size and image upload ratio per user.

Answer (score 0):

Our Solution in **3** steps.

**Step1. Create a dedicated php script that accepts a $_GET param 'imageId'**

```
<?php
//Lets call this script as 'getImage.php'.
//This script should be publicly accessible
//Example format: http://www.yourdomain.com/getImage.php?imageId=2

include ("config.php");
$query = "SELECT image FROM posts WHERE id=" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['imageId']);
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

//display the image
$im = imagecreatefromstring($r['image']); 
if ($im !== false) {
    // I assume you use only jpg
    //You may have to modify this block if you use some othe image format
    //visit: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); 
    imagejpeg($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
} else {
    echo 'error.';
} 

?>
```

**Step2. Modify your getJson.php**

```
<?php
    include ("config.php");

    //Notice the change in query.
    $query = "SELECT id,title,text,date FROM posts";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);

    $rows = array();
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        //Please replace below url with your real server url.
        $r['image'] = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/getImage.php?imageId=' . $r['id'];
        $rows[] = $r;
    }

    echo json_encode($rows);    
?>
```

**Step3 - IOS end - showing the image**

The image url is present in your repsponse array (i think postsArray). You just have to treat the image url in each row just like a normal image!

Notes:

- [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.image.php) should be enabled in php.
- We can do more optimizations. But this approach will work.

Comment: Hi @Martin E. please me know how did it go.